# Page works fine in chrome/firefox but doesn't in IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

this is my page.

essentially i'm trying to get it to work on IE as well and correctly layout my page, but for a completely unknown reason it refuses to do that. all of the  tag doesn't seem to be contained at all and the layout is completely wrong.

Whereas trying on both chrome and firefox the entire thing looks identical and works fine.

Comment: is there a specific version of IE you are testing on?

Answer (score 0):

Check here. The way IE and other browsers may proceed your floating value different.

[w3c CSS validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Funn-w14007417.newnumyspace.co.uk%2Foffers.html)

And don't forget that IE was always different and possible will be. Many web developers got bored to write special code blocks for IE and it's left to it's destiny. Suggest you to left also if you don't want to bloat your code with extra code.

Comment: i really would, but its for a project and cross compatibility is part of the grade. Just hoping that FF and Chrome are good enough.

Comment: Just as a note. Actually the aeroplane that IE displayed is inside the code. I didn't check with a tool like firebug etc but possible hidden with CSS (display:none) etc. Why not to simply delete that header from the code?

And for the width and characters, prefer to use global width and font from CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```